# Can subsequent writes be reordered when one of the variables is contained in the other?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, compiler-optimization, memory-barriers

As far as I understand, the .net framework compiler may reorder writes to different variables for performance reasons.

So if one thread executes ...

```
this.value=123;
this.initialized=true;
```

... then another thread may read `this.initialized==true`, before `this.value` has been written.

Why does this not also apply in the following case?
If one thread executes ...

```
int[] a= new int[1];
a[0] = 123;
this.array = a;
```

... then can another thread read `this.array!=null` before `a[0]` has been written?

In other words, could this code only ever print "null" or "123"?

```
int[] a = this._array;
if (a == null) 
    Console.Out.WriteLine("null"); 
else
    Console.Out.WriteLine(a[0]);
```

Is this scenario something that needs to be guarded by `lock`, `volatile`, `Thread.MemoryBarrier()`, or is this safe?

I strongly suspect this is safe, but what is the difference to the first scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Let's determine all the possible memory operations in that piece of code and understand all the dependencies between them.

```
temp1 = new int[1];   // (1) Calls a function that allocates an object.
int[] a = temp1;      // (2) A possible write to a memory location of an atomic size.
a[0] = 123;           // (3) A possible write to a memory location of an atomic size.
                      // The address of the target location depends on (2).
temp2 = a;            // (4) A possible read from a memory location of an atomic size dependent on (2).
this.array = temp2;   // (5) A possible write to a location of an atomic size dependent on (2).
```

Reordering (3) and (5) does not change the behavior of the single-threaded execution of the code. The two writes are completely independent from a single-threaded perspective. The fact that `a` holds a reference to an object is irrelevant. Therefore, the C# memory model allows the two operations to be reordered.

So if you wish to preserve the order of (3) and (5), you need to explicitly specify that in the code. If we make `a` `volatile`, then the write at (2) would have release semantics and the read at (4) would have acquire semantics, which means that (2) cannot be reordered with previous operations and that (4) cannot be reordered with subsequent operations. However, this till won't prevent both (4) and (5) from being reordered before (3). If we make `this.array` `volatile` instead, then the wrote at (5) would have release semantics, which means that (5) cannot be reordered with previous operations including (3). If making all accesses to `this.array` volatile is not necessary, you can use [Volatile.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.write?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Volatile_Write__1___0____0_) instead to make only that particular write operation volatile.

Comment: Thanks, this really surprises me. An advice for thread-save programming I have often read is this: first fully create a local object/array/dictionary (`int[] a`), then update the globally visible reference to this object (`this.array`). But if I understand you correctly, this is not safe at all, without extra precautions? Other threads may see a partially constructed array this way?

Comment: @HugoRune If you want to initialize the elements of the local array *before* publishing a reference to it to other threads, then you need to make that write volatile (release semantics).